# Starting work with SVN and basic folder structure

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, directory-structure

I have read little about TortoiseSVN and it capabilities, but I just can't understand how should I use basic structure. `/trunk /branches /tags`
I have created FSFS type repo and I have imported basic structure.
**NB!** No checkouts yet.

I also have my project files in another place.

How should I continue my work from here?

> Should I checkout repository->place
>   all files in trunk folder->add
>   them->commit them->then create tag for
>   current trunk state->create branche
>   for my goal I'm tring to
>   achive->switch to created branch and
>   work there?

By the way my repo is local and whole work too.
I thank everyone for help.

Comment: Have your looked at the Subversion book? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/  In chapter 4, they cover the usage of branches and tags.

Answer (score 1):

Branches is used when you continue to develop for a released version.  For example if you have a "Calc" product and you support the last 2 versions, your latest version is 2.0 but you keep supporting 1.0 and making fixes.

Your structure would be this:

Trunk  - new development that has not been released.  V3.0
Branches
   1.0   - you still make fixes to this branch.  Active fixes.
   2.0   - latest released version...active fixes.
Tags:
   1.0   - a snapshot of what your initially released
   2.0   - a snapshot of what you initially released.